# remove cursor style from all child elements (including nested)

Tags: jquery

I have a pdf document, that I'm trying to remove all the cursor style so I can apply my own on the `div` with the `id=#thiselemnt`. I am curious if **jQuery** could strip out all cursor **CSS** from all elements inside the containing div?

```
<div id="thiselemnt">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 621px; height: 815px; cursor: url("/content/pdftools/EllipseShape.png"), auto;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 621px; height: 815px; cursor: url("/content/pdftools/EllipseShape.png"), auto;"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 621px; height: 815px; cursor: url("/content/pdftools/EllipseShape.png"), auto;"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

</div>
```

I tried `$(string).find(*).removeAttr("style");` but this remove all style i need just to remove cursor.

Comment: Why use js? why not just use css?  You can override inline styles by using the `!important` tag - I take it your div is meant to have an id, you could do something like this: `#thiselemnt { cursor: none !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Cursor property as none rather than style attribute.

```
$(string).find(*).css("cursor",'none');
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks, I tried it but when i set my cursor on the parent element the children won't be affected because it's set to none

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#thiselemnt div").css("cursor","");
```

```js
$("#thiselemnt div").css("cursor","");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thiselemnt">

<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px;  width: 621px; height: 815px; cursor: url('/content/pdftools/EllipseShape.png'), auto;"> DIV 1</div>

</div>
```